# Text area can't scroll properly with caret

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I use a JTextArea for the chat of my simple chat program, and I added a caret so it will autoscroll when text is appended to it. This spawned an issue of the user not being able to scroll when the chat is being used a lot.

I've tried looking through options for the caret, and I looked into the scroll pane options, but there's nothing on not scrolling down when the user is scrolling.

I intend to be able to allow the user to scroll but not immediately get scrolled down because someone sent a message. What would be ideal is it it worked like Discord, where it only scrolls down when the user scrolls all the way down or something like that.

Comment: You'll have to make some determinations.  I the caret is at the end position, then you could assume that scroll should occur, otherwise don't

Comment: Is there a method I can override that lets me control when to scroll down?

Comment: Probably, but you'd be fighting just about every event that wanted to scroll down with no idea why.  Best just not to update update the position of the caret if it's not at the end of the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be ideal is it it worked like Discord, where it only scrolls down when the user scrolls all the way down or something like that.

Check out [Smart Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/). It adds an `AdjustmentListener` to the scroll bar to control scrolling:

1. When the scroll bar is at the bottom it will continue to automatically scroll.
2. When it is not at the bottom it won't scroll. The user would need to scroll to the bottom to reactivate automatic scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

My Recommendation is similar to Camickr's. Add a changelistener to the scrollbar and enable/disable caret movement based on whether or not the user is scrolled to the bottom. If the scrollbar is at the maximum, enable caret movement. If it is not, then keep it disabled.

```
YourJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().addChangeListener()
{
   //Override stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) With Caret Movement Switch
}
```

Detect and compare current scrollbar position by calling the extent, value, and maximum extent from the Model (Which is a BoundedRangeModel).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html

```
/*Where to find the needed scrollbar position values*/
YourJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getExtent()
YourJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getValue()
YourJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getMaximum() //Bottom Position

/*Pseudocode*/
if (Value + Extent == Maximum)
{
    /*Enable Caret Movement - User is at bottom of page*/ 
}
else
{
    /*Disable Caret Movement - User is not at bottom of page*/
}
```

Comment Below with any improvements or recommendations.